# How to set up LAN on the Lenovo server?

Tags: local-area-network, lenovo

I have a bizarre problem with my office Lenovo server.

Everything works when connected to my home router from the internet provider.

When I put the Mikrotik router between, the green light turns off, and the internet connection on the server stops working.

When I open DHCP Leases on Mikrotik, there is no server.

I brought the server to my office and connected it to the office router, which is also not working.

The disk is erased, and a new Ubuntu server is installed, so it cannot be an OS issue.

I have tried many things in UEFI settings, but nothing helped me.

Thank you

Comment: Bad cable or bad NIC. Possibly try to force the interface to 100Mb to see if that helps.

Comment: @vidarlo -I use the same cable while testing. Where and how to force 100mb?

Comment: Replace the cable anyway. Guess: it's a crossover cable, and your home router autosenses - consumer gear often does - but the office and Mikrotik router do not. Forcing 100MB is done in the network device settings.

Comment: I have tried different cables, and all of them are also being tested with Mac, windows and other types of devices

Comment: I have solved the issue by putting a router with a 1GB port.
The server does not want to work under 1GB speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by putting a router with a 1GB port.
The server does not want to work under 1GB speed.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this only works at 1G is unlikely, the standard ethernet 802.3 is designed implicitly for  negotiation of speeds. Speeds of 10, 100 and 1000Mb/s (the last one is equivalent to 1Gb/s) should be possible UNLESS your router / server port is manually configured to ONLY do a specific speed that the other side is not configured for. In most cases its best to set both sides to auto-negotiate. You'll find these settings in the network configuration of your devices.

Comment: The server is not accepting non-1G speeds.